# How to shutdown Wildfly 8.2.0 AS programatically

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, shutdown, wildfly-8

I am running the `Wildfly AS 8.2.0` server in `standalone` (`standalone-full-ha.xml`) mode.

I am using the below method to shutdown the `wildfly AS 8.2.0` if any exception occurs during the application deployment.

```
public static void stop() throws MalformedObjectNameException,
        InstanceNotFoundException, MBeanException, ReflectionException {

    MBeanServer mBeanServer = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
    ObjectName objectName = new ObjectName("jboss.as:management-root=server");
    try {
        mBeanServer.invoke(objectName, "shutdown", new Object[] { false },
                new String[] { boolean.class.getName() });
        _log.debug("In stop() of MBeanStopper - server stopped successfully");
    } catch (InstanceNotFoundException | ReflectionException
            | MBeanException e) {
        _log.error("In stop() of MBeanStopper and the error msg is : " + e);
    }
}
```

Response is hanging after the calling `invoke` and the server is not shutting down. I am not getting any exception as well.

When I ran this piece of code using test main program, I am getting `javax.management.InstanceNotFoundException: jboss.as:management-root=server` error but the object name is correct as I got it from JMX console and also, clicking the `shutdown()` operation of this object shutdown the server.

Could anyone please help me to resolve the issue.

Comment: try compare your code with official wiki: https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/JMX+subsystem+configuration

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by shutting the server down?